# Batch program to stop services that are running

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-scripting

Say i have a list of service all starting with the name "MyServiceFactory -". Not all of them will be started, just a handful and it varies upon service usage. I'm looking for help writing a batch program that only stops services that are running and starts these services (not all services and not restart). Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (or at least give you a start):

```
@echo off 
setlocal
if "%~1"=="" goto usage
set tmpFile=templist.txt
set tmpAnsi=templist_ansi.txt
wmic /locale:MS_409 service where "caption like '%~1' and state='Running'"  get caption /format:csv >%tmpFile%
REM this is required to convert from Unicode(UCS-2) to ANSI
type %tmpFile%>%tmpAnsi%

Echo ---------------Stopping services----------------------
Echo.
for /f "tokens=2 skip=2 delims=," %%i  in (%tmpAnsi%) do (
   wmic /locale:MS_409 service where caption="%%i" call stopservice
)

Echo --------------Starting services-----------------------
Echo.
for /f "tokens=2 skip=2 delims=," %%i  in (%tmpAnsi%) do ( 

   wmic /locale:MS_409 service where caption="%%i" call startservice
)

goto end

:usage
Echo.
Echo Usage is: 
Echo %~n0 pattern_to_check
Echo.
Echo Pattern: 
Echo [ ]  Any one character within the specified range ([a=f]) or set ([abcdef]).
Echo ^^    Any one character not within the range ([^a=f]) or set ([^abcdef].)
Echo %%    Any string of 0 (zero) or more characters
Echo _    (underscore) Any one character. Any literal underscore    
Echo         used in the query string must be escaped by placing it inside []
Echo.
Echo     If pattern contains spaces, it must be enclosed in double quotes 

:end
```

Assuming you name your batch file batch.bat, you would call it `batch.bat "MyServiceFactory -%"`.

Comment: thanks ... i get "Node," when I run the above. I will try debugging it more

Comment: This means it was not able to find any running services with given caption (descriptive name as seen in Services tool). I assumed that's what you meant by name as it included space, but there is also internal service name. Best to run `wmic`. At wmic prompt, exec `service get name,caption,displayname,state`  - this will show you all services, their caption, display name and state. Run first query from batch directly until you have result you want, changing as neccessary, and then adjust batch.

Comment: @G33kKahuna Sorry forgot to address previous to you... have a look, it should help

Comment: thanks wmz.. your code got me through, i figured out my wmic command line. This helps. powershell is offlimits for now

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using PowerShell. I have some one-liners I use to start and stop our services:

```
# Start all services with FOO in their name:
powershell -Command start-service *FOO*

# Stop all running FOO services:
powershell -Command stop-service *FOO*
```

Downside is the PowerShell command doesn't give you a status on what's happening with the service like `net start` does, but you gotta love the brevity :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning PS. Roughy equivalent 1-liner in PS would be: `get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name like 'srv_name_pattern' and state='Running'"| foreach  { stop-service $_.name; start-service $_.name}`